# can't delete document with lucene IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(term)

Tags: java, lucene

Have been struggling for this two days now, just can't delete the document  with `indexWriter.deleteDocuments(term)`

Here I will put the code which will do a test, hopefully someone could point out what I have done wrong, things that have been tried:

1. Updating the lucene version from `2.x` to `5.x`
2. Using `indexWriter.deleteDocuments()` instead of `indexReader.deleteDocuments()`
3. Tring the `indexOption` configured as `NONE` or `DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS`

here the code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestSearch {
    static SimpleAnalyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();

    public static void main(String[] argvs) throws IOException, ParseException {
        generateIndex("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");
        query("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");
        delete("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");
        query("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");

    }

    public static void generateIndex(String id) throws IOException {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/tmp/test/lucene"));
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
        FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
        fieldType.setStored(true);
        fieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
        Field idField = new Field("_id", id, fieldType);
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(idField);
        iwriter.addDocument(doc);
        iwriter.close();

    }

    public static void query(String id) throws ParseException, IOException {
        Query query = new QueryParser("_id", analyzer).parse(id);
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/tmp/test/lucene"));
        IndexReader ireader  = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDoc = isearcher.search(query, 100).scoreDocs;
        for(ScoreDoc scdoc: scoreDoc){
            Document doc = isearcher.doc(scdoc.doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get("_id"));
        }
    }

    public static void delete(String id){
        try {
             Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/tmp/test/lucene"));
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
            IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            Term term = new Term("_id", id);
            iwriter.deleteDocuments(term);
            iwriter.commit();
            iwriter.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

First `generateIndex()` will generate a index in `/tmp/test/lucene`, and  `query()` will show that `id` will be successfully queried, then `delete()` was hopefully to deleting the document, but `query()` again will prove that the deleting action failed.

Here is the pom dependency in case someone may need for a test

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-smartcn</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

desperated for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the analyzer. `SimpleAnalyzer` defines tokens as maximal strings of *letters* (`StandardAnalyzer`, or even `WhitespaceAnalyzer`, are more typical choices), so the value you are indexing gets split into the tokens: "b", "a", "b", "d", "f". The delete method you've defined doesn't pass through the analyzer though, but rather just creates a raw term. You can see this in action if you try replacing your `main` with this:

```
generateIndex("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");
query("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");
delete("b");
query("5836962b0293a47b09d345f1");
```

As a general rule, queries and terms and such *do not* analyze, QueryParser does.

For (what looks like) an identifier field, you probably don't really want to analyze this field at all. In that case, add this to the FieldType:

```
fieldType.setTokenized(false);
```

You will then have to change your query (again, QueryParser analyzes), and use `TermQuery` instead.

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("_id", id));
```

Comment: Thanks, not only for giving the right solution but also give a hint how to do a `TermQuery`